# Dynamic Images in PHP

Tags: php, image, dynamic

I am developing a CMS for clan websites.  I have a table with member ranks that members can be promoted to based on the experience points that they earn.  I would like to create a progress bar for that will display how far they have until they are promoted until the next rank.  What I want to do is fill a black bar with green based on how much xp they have earned since they've been promoted.  I have an equation that will find a percentage based on the member's progress.  For example:  if a member has made it 67% of the way from it's current rank to the next rank, 67% of the length of the black bar will be filled with green.  I hope all of this makes sense.  What do you think would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you sure images is the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div style="background-color:black;overflow:hidden;width:100px;height:30px">
    <div style="float:left;background-color:green;width:67%;height:30px">
    </div>
</div>
```

Instead of background-color you can use background-image with width 100px(for both images) and height 30px or whatever you gonna use

Comment: Yeah, i stated this in answer

Answer (score 0):

Use simple CSS -- image generating here is not what you need. But even if you need, generate 100 images once for all possible ranks percent values and use them in your script.